# Jaeger does not span elasticsearch requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, jaeger

I have a Reactive SpringBoot web application. This application uses Spring-Data-Elasticsearch to request data from Elasticsearch. The application is configured to use Jaeger tracer for API-requests monitoring.

Jaeger works ok except for Elasticsearch requests - they do not appear in nested spans of the trace. Any other web requests are present.

I have the following `gradle.build` configuration:

```
gradle.build:

  springBootVersion = '2.4.2'

  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch'

  implementation 'io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-spring-jaeger-web-starter:2.0.3'
  implementation 'io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-elasticsearch7-client:0.1.2'

application.yml

  spring:
    data:
      elasticsearch:
        client:
          reactive:
            endpoints:
             - localhost:9200
```

A jaeger run command:

```
docker run -d --name jaeger -p 5775:5775/udp -p 6831:6831/udp -p 6832:6832/udp -p 5778:5778 -p 16686:16686 -p 14268:14268 -p 14250:14250 -p 9411:9411 jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
```

Does anybody have any thoughts on why Jaeger does not span elasticsearch requests?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I did not find any solution which would work out-of-the-box. I also try sleuth/zipkin and it also did not work. So I added spans manually in WebClient via `.filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(...)` and `.filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(...)`, but it results in two separate spans. As in my case, I use reactive web client, I could not merge these two spans to calculate the duration of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that works. We need to

- reuse existed beans `Tracer` and `spanDecorators`
- add a Trace filter into ES web client configuration:

  ```
  @Configuration
  @RequiredArgsConstructor
  public class ElasticSearchClientConfiguration implements ErrorLogging {

  private final ReactiveElasticsearchRestClientProperties properties;

  private final Tracer tracer;
  private final List<WebClientSpanDecorator> spanDecorators;

  @Bean
  public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
    ClientConfiguration.MaybeSecureClientConfigurationBuilder builder =
        ClientConfiguration.builder().connectedTo(properties.getEndpoints().toArray(new String[0]));
    configureWebClient(builder);
    return builder.build();
  }

  private void configureWebClient(ClientConfiguration.TerminalClientConfigurationBuilder builder) {
    builder.withWebClientConfigurer(
        webClient ->
            webClient
                .mutate()
                .filters(addTraceExchangeFilterFunctionIfNotPresent())
                .build());
  }

  private Consumer<List<ExchangeFilterFunction>> addTraceExchangeFilterFunctionIfNotPresent() {
    return functions -> {
      if (functions.stream()
          .noneMatch(function -> function instanceof TracingExchangeFilterFunction)) {
        functions.add(new TracingExchangeFilterFunction(tracer, spanDecorators));
      }
    };
  }
  }
  ```